# Entity Framework 7 One to Many Mapping on non-key columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use fluent API to map a relationship. I am not even sure this is possible, but here is what I am attempting.

I simplified this from the actual business case. So in this version, we have TestQuestion. The TestQuestion has the ID from a Test Template Table that represents the master list of test questions, and a TestID for the specific instance of the test.

There is also a TestAnswer table. Each answer has the ID of the Test Template Question and Test ID also. However the student is allowed to answer the question as many times as they wish, with the prior answers being saved.

In the future, we want to remove the TestQuestion table. This is the first step in a refactor that will be done incremetally. So we do not want to use the ID of the test answer. So I am trying to create a relationship between the TestTemplateID and TestID columns to have a one to many relationship between TestQuestions and TestAnswers

I have been trying to configure this using fluent API in entity framework 7. Honestly, I am just guessing at what the configuration should look like. I keep getting errors stating that the number of properties in the dependent and principal roles in a relationship constraint must be identical. I've trued many attempts at the configuration. The classes and most recent attempt are below.

Is what I am attempting even possible in EF 7?

```
    public class TestQuestion
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public Guid TestTemplateQuestionID {  get; set; }

    public Guid TestID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestAnswer> Answers { get;set; } = new HashSet<TestAnswer>();   
}

public class TestAnswer
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid TestTemplateQuestionID { get; set; }

    public Guid TestID { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset AnsweredDate { get; set; }
}


        modelBuilder.Entity<TestQuestion>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Answers)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.TestTemplateQuestionID, e.TestID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<TestAnswer>()
            .HasKey(e => new { e.TestTemplateQuestionID, e.ID });
```